# ElasticSearch match if value in list of values

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm working with ElasticSearch (on a Symfony 4 project with FosElasticaBundle) and I don't know how can I build a query like :

```
Match if value in list of values
```

I have a field `"code"` and I need to retrieve an element ONLY if the value of this field `"code"` is : `"first or "second" or "third"`

I tried with terms :

- Must query : nothing is retrieved, maybe must is `"first AND "second" AND "third"` ?
- Should query : Everything is retrieved, even if I have another value than `"first or "second" or "third"`, so shoul query is useless ?

I tried with Match (should, must) or term one by one... nothing...

So, how can I do that in elasticsearch ? Thanks !

Comment: For the `should` case, can you try adding `"minimum_should_match": 1` under the `bool` key?

Comment: Which type does your field have? `text`? `keyword`?

Answer (score 0):

```
PUT some-test

PUT /some-test/doc/1
{
  "foo": "first"
}

PUT /some-test/doc/2
{
  "foo": "second"
}

PUT /some-test/doc/3
{
  "foo": "fourth"
}

POST some-test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "foo": "first second third"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

gives me

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "some-test",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "second"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "some-test",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "foo": "first"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```